# Percolation-type question involving phase transition for graded acyclic directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, percolation

Let $G$ be an acyclic directed graph with $MN$ vertices arranged into $M$ generations of $N$ vertices each. We stipulate that edges may only go from generation $j$ to generation $j+1$, so there are $(M−1)N^2$ permissible edges. Each permissible edge is chosen independently with probability $p$, and the resulting subset of permissible edges is used to construct $G$.

The quantity of interest is the probability $P(p)$ that a randomly-chosen vertex $x$ in the first generation of $G$ is connected by a directed path to a random-chosen vertex $y$ in the $M$th generation of $G$. As $N$ becomes large for fixed $M$, one expects a phase transition in $P$ from near $0$ to near $1$ as $p$ crosses some threshold $p_0$.

**Question:** What is this threshold $p_0$ in terms of $M$ and $N$?

For example, when $M=3$ (first interesting case), it seems that the threshold is $p_0=N^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, and I would guess that $p_0=N^{-\frac{M−2}{M−1}}$ in general.

Is this correct, and how does one prove it? Or where can I find this problem analyzed? I have found many somewhat-relevant sources on percolation, but they mostly involve lattices or Erdös-Rényi graphs.

Comment: I would look into the literature on "directed percolation" for techniques. Interestingly, it seems that the sort of graph you're describing [doesn't seem to have a standard name](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048722/a-name-for-layered-directed-graph-as-in-a-fully-connected-neural-network).

Comment: Thanks... I do believe that's the most promising topic to search, but so far I've found mostly lattice-related work.  On Math Stack Exchange, someone asks for a name for this kind of graph [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042622/name-for-stratified-or-synchronized-directed-acyclic-graph?rq=1), and accepts the answer "cover digraph of a graded poset." Evidently the intent is to include only edges representing covering relations.